# Azure containers already exists?

Tags: azure

In Azure SDK for PHP,  Is there any way to check if the containers already exists in the account? Any function or call exist that might let me know the existance of the containert?

Comment: Just curious as to why you need to check the existence since you normally call something like `createContainerIfNotExists`

Comment: Haven't worked with Azure SDK for PHP (so I can't tell you the exact function) but other alternatives would be to try and list just 1 blob or get blob container properties for the blob container in question and see if you're getting a 404 (Resource not found) error. If you don't get this error that means container exists.

Comment: @f0x - createContainerIfNotExists doesnt exists in the php API, or at least, I cant find it. Could you point me to it, if you know where it is?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

try {
    $blobRestProxy->getContainerProperties("mycontainer");
    // The container exists.
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    // Code ContainerNotFound (404) means the container does not exist.
    $code = $e->getCode();
}
```